# The container from the worker node can't join the swarm's attachable network

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I encounter a problem when using the 'docker run' on the worker node,
the scenario is as follows:

I have following three VMs in my environment,
and they are already in the Swarn mode.

```
VM.1 -> Master node in the Swarm
VM.2 -> Worker node in the Swarm
VM.3 -> Worker node in the Swarm
```

and I've also created the overlay network in this environment via:

```
docker network create --attachable --driver overlay --subnet 10.10.0.0/16 --gateway 10.10.0.1 test-net
```

and the overlay network is created successfully

```
# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
fc1b70304011        bridge              bridge              local
f9ca924c1a4d        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
ea8fc696d6f1        host                host                local
r311gaq7iobo        ingress             overlay             swarm
bd08afac574d        none                null                local
wb7vfpxzdkyt        test-net            overlay             swarm
```

but, once I use 'docker run' to run a container and let it join the "test-net" from the worker node(VM.2 and VM.3), then I will encounter the following problem:

```
    # docker run -itd --name=test --net=test-net kafka:latest
    c0324e6c3a8720b291cfc3aa7980846348f7a4450381036927924c52d343f622
    docker: Error response from daemon: error creating external 
    connectivity network: 
    cannot create network 
    246bb018a15a6641a9cb26afec30c62eb4714816cfc0a307786c8a209a2418e6 
    (docker_gwbridge): 
     conflicts with network 
     0093ca50dcbcf729aeeae537f424727b674843312ef63ea647db48c7b0077e45 
     (docker_gwbridge): networks have same bridge name.
```

but, it will be worked if I use the same 'docker run' command on the Master node, I've google this problem for serval times but still not understand what is happening on the worker node...

Thanks for your reading and help!

Comment: Did you run docker network ls on the worker node? 
Could you try running any service with --mode=global on this network and if you get tasks on all nodes, try to attach a container on the worker node after that?

Answer (score 0):

During investigating,

this issue is not 100% reproduced on the other machine/distribution.

some machines can be worked by `docker run -itd --name=test --net=test-net kafka:latest`

but, if the way above is not worked in specific machine,

then you can try to run the container without `--net` first,

then use `docker network connect --ip <ipaddress> <network> <container>` for

appending the specific network at your container.